# CSS: Why is my text not the specified colour?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

My navigation bar currently should be set so that the text is white however this is not what is happening. Instead it is randomly showing as blue for different links in the navigation bar at different times and I don't understand why. I have asked several people in my university and they don't know why either.

Here is an image of what is happening - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFjz.png

Here is my CSS code for this:

// colours for variants of links

```
a:link
{
color: whitesmoke;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited 
{
color: whitesmoke;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover 
{
color: grey;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active
{
color: whitesmoke;
}

#navigation_bar
{
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid #222;
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
background-color: #080808;
background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
}

#navigation_bar_li 
{
list-style-type: none;
box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0px #444;
border-right: 2px solid #222;
float: left;
position: relative;
list-style: none;    
}

#navigation_bar_li a
{
 padding: 16px 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font: "bold"; 
 color: #f3ffff; 
 text-shadow:  0 .5px  0 whitesmoke; 
}

.navigation_bar, .navigation_bar ul
{  
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;  
}
```

HTML Code is here -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
<title>E-Portfolio Main</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation_bar">
        <div>
        <ul id="navigation_bar_li">

        <li><a href="index.html">Main Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="Games_Page.html">Games Page</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>

    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated I just cannot see what is making the text blue.

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: Apologies added it now.

Comment: Is this a browser specific issue or does it show up everywhere? Also I loaded your html and css in fiddle and my rendered html is not the same as you have in your pic. I assume their is more to the page that you left out then?

Comment: You haven't provided all the styles. Can you give us the link to page or at least to stylesheet?

Comment: The problem is not reproduceable with the CSS and HTML code provided.

Comment: What browser are you using? It happens with all of mine. I have no idea why. :/

Comment: There may be more CSS affecting your HTML. Hit F12 in whatever browser is doing this, then inspect the blue `<a>` menu items to see what CSS is being applied.